# Cerrar varias ventanas toplevel

Tags: tkinter

quisiera cerrar varias ventanas toplevel abiertas, cuando llama a una función a través de un button, pero solo me cierra la última ventana abierta.

```
def cerrar_vtn(self):
    self.vtn_directorio.destroy()
```

Hay alguna manera, de obtener las ventanas abiertas y cerrarlas ??

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible cerrar todas las instancias de una ventana hija o `tk.Toplevel()`, hay varias formas entre esas está usar una variable tipo lista o una lista en donde se inicie una `tk.Toplevel()` general y al destruir se cierren todas las instancias de ese Toplevel abiertas o solo por medio de la detección del widget usando `winfo_children()` y luego usando el nombre del widget el cual es un `tk.Toplevel()` y luego destruir el widget el cual es el `tk.TopLevel()`.

**Así quedaría como un ejemplo:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class WindowExample(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Agregar los widgets....

        labelExample = tk.Label(self, text="Este es un ejemplo de cómo cerrara todas las ventanas Toplevel")
        labelExample.place(x=13, y=15)

        OpenVentanaButton = tk.Button(self, text="Ocultar el label", command=self.DestruirVentanasAbiertas)
        CerrarventanaButton = tk.Button(self, text="Mostrar el label", command=self.AbrirVentana)

        OpenVentanaButton.place(x=485, y=12)
        CerrarventanaButton.place(x=359, y=12)

    def AbrirVentana(self): # Abrir una ventana TopLevel de prueba
        ventanaTopLevelPruebas = tk.Toplevel()
        ventanaTopLevelPruebas.mainloop()

    def DestruirVentanasAbiertas(self): # Cerrara todas las ventanas
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            if isinstance(widget, tk.Toplevel):
                widget.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = WindowExample()
    root.title('Ejemplo ventana: Cerrara ventanas Toplevel abiertas')
    root.geometry('600x80')
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos
```